# NTC connection and noise

Tags: noise, thermistor

I have several times used an NTC in series a resistor to sense temperature with Arduino.

There can be two connections:

**1)** NTC between the power supply and the resistor (resistor going to ground).

**2)** NTC under the resistor, i.e., one of the two terminals of the NTC to ground.

I have always used the 1) approach because it guarantees me an approximately linear relationship between the voltage generated by the change in the NTC resistance and the temperature ... whereas the second one does not.

However, I am now wondering what problems may arise with the 1) configuration since the NTC is a 2-terminal device and neither terminal is grounded.
Noise? Interference? Disturbances?

I ask for some general theory applied, possibly, to this example I have brought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference at all to the linearity, all other things being equal.

The divider situation is symmetrical and (assuming the Arduino ADC is using the power supply as a reference) no difference in the performance.

So, it's really up to you which way you connect them. A grounded sensor may be preferable if your circuit is grounded so a short from one lead to ground does not short out your power supply.

Either way, the thermistor beta and resistor you choose will determine what results you get. Typically you want the resistor to equal the thermistor resistance near the middle of the range since the differential output of the divider (in terms of volts per Kelvin temperature change) will decrease on either side of that value. That may not be possible when self-heating effects are taken into account (you may need to use a higher value resistor than optimal or  use a more complex circuit).

Typical NTC thermistors are very nonlinear so if you try to get a wide temperature range you may need a lot more bits in your ADC than the result you're expecting. Cheap ASIC digital thermometers use something like 13-bit oscillator-based ADC conversion for this reason, and even so you'll may see the temperature display jumping multiple 'counts' near the top of the range.

Comment: If you try to solve the voltage divider in both cases you will notice that only in the case with the NTC between supply and ground you can approximate the voltage linearly ... since you get Vo=Vi/(1+Rntc/R) ~= 1-Rntc/R when Rntc/R-->0

Comment: It is not clear to me when you say "you want the resistor to equal the thermistor resistance near the middle of the range." Do you mean that the resistance used in the resistive divider must be similar/equal to R0 of the NTC specified in the datasheet? That is, if R0=10k then I put 10k ... while if R0=33k then I use 33k

Comment: I mean if you want to measure a temperature range over which the thermistor changes from 10kΩ to 30kΩ your series resistor should be something like 20kΩ, no matter what R0 is specified as. If you have a particular temperature of interest (say near human body temperature) then the thermistor resistance at that temperature should be the series resistor, ideally.

Comment: The linearity is dominated by the nonlinearity of the thermistor with temperature in the case of NTC thermistors with typical beta ~= 4000. The change of current makes very little difference. In any case, the same thing applies if you swap the thermistor and resistor, just subtract the digital reading from full scale count and you'll get the same number.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answers! Let me give you a practical example, so maybe I understand a little more. I have an NTC with R0=33k to be connected in series with a resistor. I will use Arduino (10 bit ADC) to read the voltage value at the ends of the NTC. The temperature varies from 25°C to 50°C. What resistor value (the one in series to the NTC) do you recommend I use? It is still not 100% clear to me how to choose it

Comment: The value of the NTC at around 37.5 degrees C, so probably about 22K. The ADC needs to be happy with the max resistance (at minimum temperature) or you need a buffer op-amp, but that’s a different question than this one.

Comment: To find the 22kohm that you wrote, I should calculate Rntc(37.5°C)=R0*e^(1/T37-1/T0) ... the NTC I am using has beta=4220 and R0=33k ... but measured in the vacuum with the multimeter I have R0=37k because of the long wires I soldered to the ends. Therefore: Rntc(37.5°C)=R0*e^(1/T37-1/T0) = 37k*e^(1/310.65 - 1/298.15) = 21k. Am I wrong?      (the temperature is in kelvin)

Comment: Sounds correct. It's not really critical.  You could use 20.0kΩ 1% for example.

Comment: I soldered on a pcb an NTC (R0=10k at 25°C) with a Rseries=10k .. and I want to use it to measure/monitor the temperature of an object in the range [37 ... 43]°C. So Taverage=40°C and, as we said, I should choose Rseries=Rntc(40°C)=5k. I, however, soldered on the pcb 10k! In your experience .. how much does it change the truthfulness of the result .. in other words, will I have a very large error?